Rule of succession, proof using PDFs.
So I have looked at proofs of rule of succession on Wikipedia and here and most either handwave or use likelihood which I do not understand. I was wondering if the approach I took makes sense and is rigorous. I also have a few questions along the way.
Assume that $X_1,\cdots X_n$ are the results of coin flips with a coin of unknown bias $p$ and that $\sum_{1}^{n} X_i=s$ where $X_i=1$ means heads. For simplicity let $A$ denote the even that all flips are heads. We assume, due to lack of knowledge, that $p$ is uniformly distributed between $0$ and $1$ and want to know what is the probability that the next flip will be heads.
First of all, are $X_i$ random variables? They are distributed $X_i \sim Ber(p)$ but $p \sim U(0,1)$. Does it make sense to have this sort of nested random variable thing?
My approach to proving the rule:
$$P(p\leq x |A)\stackrel{\text{Bayes theorem}}{=}\frac{P(A \cap p\leq x)}{P(A)}\stackrel{\text{law of total probability}}{=}\frac{\int_{0}^{x}P(A|p=t)dt}{\int_{0}^{1}P(A|p=t)dt}$$
since $A\sim Bin(p,n)$ we know that the above is
$$\frac{\int_{0}^{x}t^s(1-t)^{(n-s)} dt}{\int_{0}^{1}t^s(1-t)^{(n-s)}dt}=F_{p|A}(x)$$
Now take the derivative get the pdf, which becomes the beta pdf. From here we just take the expecation at the answer is $\frac{s+1}{n+2}$
Now looking at wikipedia the answer to the question is $E(p|A)$, why is that? Is that just one way of interpreting what the question is asking?
